Visual Studio Code builds solution if I reference DLLs directly, but not if I pull them in from nuget packages
I have a .Net core solution that references several .Net 4.8 custom DLL's.  If I reference the dll's directly, Visual Code builds without issue.  However, when I pack these DLL's into nupkg's, I get these two errors when I try to build:
The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild.
The "CheckIfVBCSCompilerWillOverride" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.203" directory.
Visual Studio 2022 will build the solution either way, so this seems to be Visual Code related.  Thanks in advance.
